Solution verification: Eigenvalues of unitary matrix
If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is unitary, then the eigenvalues of $A$ have module $1$.

$Av=\lambda v\implies \langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle \lambda v,\lambda v\rangle =\lambda\overline{\lambda}\langle v,v\rangle=|\lambda|^2||v||^2.$
Now, $\langle Av,Av\rangle =||Av||^2=||v||^2$ since unitary matrices preserve norm.
Furthermore, $|\lambda|^2||v||^2=||v||^2$. And from here, we can conclude the desired result.
Is this solution correct?

Yes, it is correct.
